# Epsilon-delta definition of a limit with a given delta

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove this simple limit using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow2}x^2 = 4$. However, I am trying to prove it with the given $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon}$ (which is a correct $\delta$, according to my textbook). Thus, I am trying to show that $|x^2 - 4| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x - 2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5+\epsilon}$.

What I have come up with so far is the following. Clearly, $|x^2 - 4| = |x+2||x-2|$. This means that in order for $|x^2 - 4| < \epsilon$, I need to attain the bound $|x+2| < 5 + \epsilon$, since we already know that $|x-2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon}$. However, I have not been able to find a way to do this. The given bound of $|x-2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5+\epsilon}$ implies that $|x+2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon} + 4$, but this does not get me anywhere in showing that $|x^2 - 4| < \epsilon$. I feel like there is a trick here that I am simply not seeing that does not involve bounding $|x+2|$. Any push in the right direction would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm...surely, there is no such thing as a 'correct' $\delta$.

Comment: @hellotinfish: There is no *the* correct $\delta$, but there are certainly many "a correct \delta"s.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yea but unfortunately there are a minority of people who memorize the choice of $\delta$ without actually going through an epsilon-delta proof themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The given bound of $|x-2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5+\epsilon}$ implies that $|x+2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon} + 4$

That's correct. Then, what's left to show is that:

$$
\frac{\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon} + 4 \le 5 + \epsilon \;\;\iff\;\; \epsilon^2+5 \epsilon + 5 \ge 0
$$

The latter inequality holds true for all $\,\forall \epsilon \gt 0\,$, so it follows that $|x+2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon} + 4 \le 5 + \epsilon\,$, so in the end $|x^2-4| = |x+2| \cdot |x-2| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon} \cdot (5 + \epsilon) = \epsilon$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  As noted in @stevengregory's comment, the more direct way to prove $\,\frac{\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon} + 4 \le 5 + \epsilon\,$ is to note that $\frac{\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon} \lt 1\,$, thus $\frac{\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon}+4 \lt 5 \lt 5+\epsilon\,$.

Comment: Ahh, I see! I did not think to bound $\frac{\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon} + 4$ itself. Thank you very much for the help!